# What treebank was used to train the Stanford CoreNLP Spanish constituency parser?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I've searched the docs and the FAQs but I have yet to find the answer.  Was the IULA treebank from the Pompeu Fabra Uni used?  https://www.iula.upf.edu/recurs01_tbk_uk.htm

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser was trained on a preprocessed version of the AnCora Spanish 3.0 corpus.

You can find more information about the training data and the preprocessing at

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/spanish-faq.html .